# Stack output concept

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am new FORTRAN user.
I want to write the output in stack way without deleting the previous one. Suppose we have three outputs A,B,C for one one one "ELECTRON1". When we run the code for another "ELECTRON2" then all previous outputs are over written. So I want to write in a stack way with one blank line.

Please suggest me how I can do it.......
I am very greatful to you...

Regards

Answer (score 1):

if you do

```
write (*,*) a, b,c
then later
write (*, *)
write (*, *) a, b, c
```

you should see six numbers on your screen, in two lines, separated by a blank line.

Or if you do this in a loop:

```
do i=1, N
... computations
    write (*, *)
    write (*, *) a, b, c
end do
```

You should get N lines of 3 numbers separated by blank lines.

Is this what you want?

If not, please clarify your question or post some code.